# How to edit/reset Alarm Manager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, preferences, listpreference

*I've set up a Preference Screen in which i have a list preference which allows user to select time interval to notify them.*

*They can choose whether to notify them after every 2,4,8,10 or 12 hours.*

**Here's my list preference:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<ListPreference
            android:title="Notification Timer"
            android:summary="Select when to Notify"
            android:dialogTitle="Show Notification after every:"
            android:positiveButtonText="OK"
            android:negativeButtonText="Cancel"
            android:entries="@array/entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/entries"
            android:key="listPrefs" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Here's my Settings.class file:**

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("listPrefs");
        listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                return false;
            }
        });
        @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

*I want to **update or reset Alarms every time the user changes the time interval of notifying him/her**. for ex- If user selects 4 hours than he/she must be notified after 4 hours or if user chooses 10 hours than he/she must be notified after 10 hours!*

Comment: See the `AlarmManager` documentation.  If you are having a specific issue with the APIs or a crash, please provide more information.

Comment: guys please write the reason for down vote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Copy the following methods to your *Setting.java* file:

   ```
   private final int NOTIFICATION_TIMER = 11;

   public void setAlarm(Context mContext,int requestCode,long time) {

       Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, requestCode, myIntent,0);

       cancelAlarmIfExists(mContext,requestCode,myIntent);

       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis()+time), time, pendingIntent);
   }

   public void cancelAlarmIfExists(Context mContext,int requestCode,Intent intent){
       try {
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, requestCode, intent,0);
           AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
           am.cancel(pendingIntent);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call them from the `onPreferenceChange()` method. Like so:

   ```
   listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

           long time = 34352355253; // calculate millisecons from change value by user.
           setAlarm(Settings.this,NOTIFICATION_TIMER,time);
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this anwer Bro, but it's showing an error here: `setAlarm(this,NOTIFICATION_TIMER,time);`
The Error is: The method setAlarm(Context, int, long) in the type Settings is not applicable for the arguments (new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener(){}, int, long)

Comment: dude it is just static value. you have to calculate that value when user select it from list. If user clicks on 2 hours. You need to calculate milliseconds for 2 hours and assign it ti time variable.

Comment: please read the comment along with it. And try something with your own.

Answer (score 2):

FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT has the same effect as above answer

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, notifIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```