# Android and specific notifications

Tags: android, service, notifications

I want my app to notify users of specific events that can occur at a certain time.

I know how to send a notification knowing the exact time of it, but things get a little complicated for me when I want to trigger notifications at times that are unknown at app install (notifications whose time can change or which depend on a specific event).

**Here are two cases in which I don't know how to trigger a notification :**

- Send a notification every day at a time **that can change from day to day**. Say I want to notify users that it's sunrise time, do I need a Service to run permanetly an calculate for each day the time of sunset and trigger a notification when the time comes ?
- Send a notification everytime something new in the community occurs. I don't want to notify users of an update, but just of a particular event at a certain time. **How do I send notifications to them**?

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first option i would use a `AlarmManager`. It will execute a function on a specific time, that can be set on app startup. Everytime the AlarmManager executes and sends a notification to the user, it should re-calculate the next message time and reset the `AlarmManager`. ( see how to reset [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009195/how-to-edit-reset-alarm-manager) )

For your second scenario you could use a library like [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/). It's a verry usefull library for registering users for pushnotifications and sending messages from a website to your users. You can choose groups of users or specific users for sending messages and you can customize the look of your pushmessages ( add buttons, images, .. etc).

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try this out. But for the second solution, is there any way of sending a notification without using a library ?

Comment: Yes there is, OneSignal has a faboulus interface for sending push notifications. You can design & sceduel messages to be send at a given time to a specific group, user or just to everybody. It also ( if you're looking for expanding your app to iOS ) can send push notifications to iOS device, making it a nice cross platform solution! Check it out!