# Background repeating task with onboot

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

Hello i want to make a background service to update the data of my app and repeat it once a day, also i want the service to start onboot. I have the following code:

```
public class OnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Create Intent
        context.startService(new Intent(context, BackgroundServiceHandler.class));
    }

}
```

I have a settings menu so the user can choose the hour of the repeating alarm.
How can i reset the time of the alarmmanager? Where i have to put the code of the alarm manager? Do i have to use service or intentservice? How to check if service is running?

Alarm manager code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmService.class);
    intent.putExtra("i", 3);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 9, intent, 0);

    // every day at 9 am
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // if it's after or equal 9 am schedule for next day
    if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 9) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); // add, not set!
    }
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- > How can i reset the time of the alarmmanager?

[How to edit/reset Alarm Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009195/how-to-edit-reset-alarm-manager)

- > Where i have to put the code of the alarm manager?

For example you can place that code in static method and call it from place where user set time and from `OnBootReceiver`. How to implement class which will receive event `OnBoot` please check that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup-keep-running-when-activity-is-in-backgrou).

- > Do i have to use service or intentservice?

[Service vs IntentService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice)

- > How to check if service is running?

[Check if service is running on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588910/check-if-service-is-running-on-android)